# SQL magento sales report query in reports

Tags: mysql, magento

I want to add attributes like color,size etc and more attributes in below query 
I don't know what is the attribute query Please help me to find out this

```
$form = Start Date 
$to = End Date
$this->_reset();
$this->getSelect()        
    ->joinInner(array(
          'i' => $this->getTable('sales/order_item')),
          'i.order_id = main_table.entity_id'
   ) 
   ->where('i.parent_item_id is null')
   ->where("i.created_at BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to."'")
   ->where('main_table.state = \'complete\'')
   ->columns(array('ordered_qty' => 'count(distinct `main_table`.`entity_id`)'));
```

[image]

Thanks
Jitendra

Comment: Jitendra,can please put the hole modules...

Comment: here site   http://www.summasolutions.net/blogposts/custom-reports-magento

Comment: any one help for this

Comment: can  u please  tell me ,are you using configurbale product  ya simple product...

Comment: both product are available, my report title are like Product Name size color ordered qty

Comment: k.. i will try it on night.... hope ,i will give you some solutions.....

Answer (score 0):

The sales order items table does not store every single attribute of every single product sold. Therefore you have to decide whether you want to add those attributes to the sales order item table when you create a sales order - or - if you want to just look them up in the product catalogue.

The problem with taking the first approach is that you will not be able to get data for orders made to date, just orders following on from now.

The problem with the second approach is that if you change or delete products in your main catalog then you will no longer have that data in your report. This may not be a problem if you are never going to change your products, however why run the risk? There is also another problem - performance. For every line item your report will have to run queries on the product catalog to get attribute values, this has a considerable performance penalty that may not be obvious until you get a significant amount of orders through.

If we take the first approach then there is not a lot of point modifying the original Magento provided report. You might as well write your own module for it.

In this module you will need a setup script to add your required columns on to your sales order items table.

You will also need event observers to move the attributes into the sales quote and onto the sales order object at checkout. Without this your attribute data might not make it into the report.

You can save attribute values by Magento option value ids, however, you might change your attribute options at some stage so these cannot be looked up. Therefore, rather than store the ids, e.g. '412' you will need to store the labels, e.g. 'Red'. In that way the report will work this time next year and have meaningful values in it.

You will also need an admin grid that makes a collection from the simple products rather than the 'visible' (i.e. including configurable) line items in the sales order items table.

If you are averse to adding in extra columns to the sales order items table because you don't want the table to get too big, you can add your attribute values to the serialised data Magento uses to store superattribute option selections and write your own custom column renderer to extract the data and show it in your report.

There is a considerable amount of coding to get the report you want and for it to be futureproofed against changes to the catalog/attribute option values. All of the required steps can be tackled a piece at a time once you have a specification of exactly what it is you want your report to be like.